# c# slimdx offscreen rendering, output to multiple windows / monitors

Tags: c#, wpf, device, creation, slimdx

Okay, I'm rewriting this post because I had a really specific question but I think it might be more useful to just explain what I want to do :)

I'm working in WPF with SlimDX.
The target is a program that initializes a Direct3D device, and is able to render cool D3D11 gfx to an offscreen rendertarget.

Users can add output-windows, and output-windows can either be full-screen on any connected monitor, or just a window.
An output window just shows a *part* of the offscreen-backbuffer.
So - I have a very highres offscreen texture / backbuffer, and I want zero to N output windows basicly rendering a fullscreen quad with uv-coords specifying an area in that highres texture.

My questions are :

- What is the 'correct' way in SlimDX to initialize a Direct3D device in the main application, without any output-window / swapchain yet ?
- Once I have a 'global' Direct3D 11 device, how do I set up an offscreen rendertarget texture where I can render cool stuff to ?
- once I have an offscreen rendertarget with cool stuff rendered in it, how do I set up a system so I can add / remove windows that show *parts* of this rendertarget ?
  (For each dynamicly created / removed window, add / remove part of the swapchain?)

I know these problems are quite specific and most people don't ever want to render stuff in the background to be displayed on different devices, but hey - that's what stackoverflow is for  :)